# Eeek: The "help" link on meta redirects to "math.stackexchange.com/help"

Tags: support, help-center

Previously, we had a nice separate "faq" for meta.math.SE.

However, with the advent of the so-called "help center", if I now click the "help" button on the top, next to my username, I'm being redirected to the main help, viz [math.stackexchange.com/help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help).

This is unlikely to be the desired behaviour. Moreover, **where has the meta FAQ page gone?!**

If it weren't for the large knowledge base the meta regulars form, newcomers to meta would (and occasionally nonetheless do) have a hard time figuring things out (like the ubiquitous confusion about meta votes, which are used a bit different than votes on main).

---

NB. This just goes on the heap with the rest of the complaints on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/222340). *What were they thinking?!*

Comment: Does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) help?

Comment: This is by design (I want to say that I didn't design it). The original meta bits can be found in a [little corner](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) of the help pages. Less accessible? I think so.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Ok, good to know it is still up. However, this particular section of the "help" is _not_ initially visible. Yugh, what a (insert expletive) design.

Comment: We're still trying to figure out the best way to deal with the help center on meta; we'll likely make the /whats-meta article the landing page when you click on "help" from meta. We've had a backlog of issues to deal with, but I hope to find a better solution to this problem in the next week or so.

Comment: @Laura: should I retag the question (bug) or (feature-request) so it remains visible to the team? Or is the current tags okay?

Comment: @WillieWong Current tags are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "help" link on meta now points to: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

You'll notice that this does still take you back to the main help page. Unfortunately, the only way we really could avoid that is to duplicate the help center for every meta site, which would make maintenance a little bit crazy. I know it's not ideal to be taken from meta to main without intentionally deciding to do that, but I think the most important thing is that when you click "help" from meta, you're now taken to a page that explains what meta is (like the old meta FAQ did).

Comment: I thank you for taking the time to address this issue.